# How to redirect back to current page after delete form request in phoenix framework using scrivener

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using scrivener_ecto and scrivener_html in phoenix framework.
I have a contact list that has 300 contact in it.
When I click delete a contact in for page 6, after submit deletion, I redirect to first page of contact list.
I want to stay in current page(like page 6) after a deletion. How can I do this?

I tried to get params info from delete controller, but it has no page information(query params) I tried

```
IO.inspect conn.query_string
```

but it returns ""
here is delete action in person_controller.ex

```
  def action(conn, _) do
    user = conn.assigns.current_user
    phonebook = Contact.get_phonebook!(conn.params["phonebook_id"], user.id)
    arg_list = [conn, conn.params, phonebook]
    apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn), arg_list)
  end

  def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}, phonebook) do
    person = Contact.get_person!(id, phonebook.id)
    {:ok, _person} = Contact.delete_person(person)

    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Contact deleted successfully.")
    |> redirect(to: phonebook_path(conn, :show, phonebook))
  end
```

in template

```
<%= button to: phonebook_person_path(@conn, :delete, @phonebook.id, person.id), method: "delete", data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], class: "btn btn-danger" do %><i class="material-icons icon-button">close</i><% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post code/details about your delete action and the contact list action that calls it?

Comment: @Sheharyar I edited post

Comment: As a side note, your `conn.params` are redundant. The second argument of the method is the `params` map. You also shouldn't use apply, and instead directly call the other method here. [See this](https://hastebin.com/solewekexi.sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the page number again in the template:

```
<%= button to: phonebook_path(@conn, :delete, phonebook.id, person.id, page: @conn.params["page"]) %>
```

And then propagate it back to your `show` action in `delete`:

```
conn
|> put_flash(:info, "Contact deleted successfully")
|> redirect(to: phonebook_path(conn, :show, phonebook, page: conn.params["page"]))
```

Comment: Thanks! It solves my problem.. and I just copied action function from other tutorial, and I don't know exactly what it is doing. I tried to find docs about action, but couldn't find it. Can you give me a link to action function? and why I shouldn't use and also about conn.params.

Comment: The [Phoenix Guides](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/controllers.html#content) are a great place to get started.